# Drush syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in webform.module

Tags: 7, webforms, drush

When I try to run drush right now I get this error:

```
-bash-4.1$ drush pm-list
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
Error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in
<site location>/sites/all/modules/webform/webform.module,
line 4654
```

Here is the function where the error occurs:

```
/**
 * Get a list of all available component definitions.
 */
function webform_components($include_disabled = FALSE, $reset = FALSE) {
  static $components, $enabled;

  if (!isset($components) || $reset) {
    $components = array();
    $disabled = array_flip(webform_variable_get('webform_disabled_components'));
    foreach (module_implements('webform_component_info') as $module) {
      $module_components = module_invoke($module, 'webform_component_info');
      foreach ($module_components as $type => $info) {
        $module_components[$type]['module'] = $module;
        $module_components[$type]['enabled'] = !array_key_exists($type, $disabled);
      }
      $components += $module_components;
    }
    drupal_alter('webform_component_info', $components);
    uasort($components, function($a, $b) {
      return strnatcasecmp($a['label'], $b['label']);
    });
    $enabled = array_diff_key($components, $disabled);
  }

  return $include_disabled ? $components : $enabled;
}
```

Line 4654 is the one that starts with "uasort" (near the bottom). I'm using

- PHP 5.6.15
- Drupal 7.41
- Webform 7.x-4.12

Drush was working for the whole project (up till now) and webform was installed near the start of the project.

Comment: Sounds like you're using a different php version for CLI - that syntax is valid as of >= php5.3. What does `php -v` show you from the command line?

Comment: Oh you're right, 5.2.17. Didn't know it was different things. Thanks, this helps narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems to be a problem with the anonymous function. I read some post that talk about a problem with eAccelerator and the PHP version. The recomendations are:

- disabling eAccelerator and opcode caching
- replacing eAccelerator with Zend's opcache
- reverting to PHP 5.3

You can read more at:

- The Webform issue about "[Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION](https://www.drupal.org/node/2467239)"
- http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#113422

Comment: Bluehost only has options for php 5.4 & 5.6. I tried both without luck but I've been on 5.6 since the project started about 2 months ago (this is a recent issue). Don't have eAccelerator or opcode caching installed. Tried this solution as well but no luck https://www.drupal.org/node/2467239#comment-10238491